# How to stop DispatchGroup manually (When we reach a certain value) and get it to call .notify (finish all executions manually)

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue, dispatchgroup

This is different than wanting to stop after a period of time.
An example of possible use case:

```swift
func calculate(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int, completion: @escaping (([Int]) -> Void)) {
        let enumerated = nums.enumerated()
        let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var answer: [Int] = []
        queue.async { () -> Void in
            for (xIndex, xElement) in nums.enumerated() {
                queue.async(group: group) {
                    for (yIndex, yElement) in enumerated where yIndex != xIndex {
                        if xElement + yElement == target {
                            answer = [xIndex, yIndex]
                            //I want it to end here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            group.notify(queue: queue) {
                completion(answer)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am attaching each of the inner for loop to the dispatch group so they are calculating at the same time, but when the answer is found let's say in the 3rd for run, there is no need for the Dispatch group to calculate others and should stop like all the tasks are completed and call `group.notify`

Basically I want it to `return` when it reaches the answer. Is there any way to do this? if so how?

From what I've researched, we can use `group.leave` to explicitly say that a block in the group finished executing, but how can it be done so *all* the blocks in the group finish when we reach the desired point?

Comment: I used `group.suspend()` in my example and had it print the `answer` before it, it printed twice, so I think it's still not stopping *all* the executions. or am I doing something wrong here and need to study it more?

Comment: Have you thought about using NSOperation, break the work into Operations, when first one of them succeeds, cancel them all. Be sure to check for cancellation in the operation.

Comment: No, didn't know about NSOperation, and if it does work it that's awesome and thanks for pointing it out! but still, I would like to know if it can be accomplished with `DispatchGroup`

Comment: NSOperation is built on top of GCD, so you could build your own 'operation' abstraction on top of GCD too, but it's not trivial to implement.